# installing and running Ubuntu from a partition on a laptop

Tags: dual-boot

I've downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.3 to a DVD and to my laptop.  It's an Acer with Win7.  I have  a 100G partition set aside for installing and running Ubuntu.  After download I just get a disk image file about 1G in size.  "ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64"  nothing runs it.  I'm sure I'm missing a step in the process.  I used to have an older version of Ubuntu loaded and sort of running but I uninstalled that one.
What's going wrong?  Did I miss a step?

Comment: You now need to boot from the DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to reset your computer, change the boot to start looking the DVD content (press F9 or F2 at the beginning, it depends on the computer). That's all, ubuntu will load from the DVD and will allow you to install ubuntu.

Be careful with new UEFI boot system. If your computer presents this system, you will need to deactivate to access the boot menu once you reset it. You have hundreds of web pages to learn how to deactivate UEFI system.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the image burned ok onto the dvd without errors then all you need to do to make it boot is change the bios setting's to boot the disk drive first..

Usually you will need to restart the laptop and press F9 or F2 or Esc key to get into the bios, once there go to the boot order and moved the cd/disk drive up to the top then simply exit saving changes and restart the laptop.